# HMRC Fraud Prevention Headers - Delphi

Tags: delphi

I'm using Delphi (REST) to submit HMRC Fraud Prevention Headers in the MTD VAT Sandbox.

These are working:-

```
RESTRequest1.Params.AddHeader('Gov-Client-Connection-Method', UriEncode('DESKTOP_APP_DIRECT'));
RESTRequest1.Params.AddHeader('Gov-Client-Device-ID', UriEncode('beec798b-b366-47fa-b1f8-92cede14a1ce'));
RESTRequest1.Params.AddHeader('Gov-Client-Local-IPs', UriEncode('10.1.2.3'));
RESTRequest1.Params.AddHeader('gov-client-mac-addresses', UriEncode('30-65-EC-6F-C4-58'));
```

These aren't working (using the HMRC data examples):-

```
RESTRequest1.Params.AddHeader('Gov-Client-Timezone', UriEncode('UTC+00:00'));
RESTRequest1.Params.AddHeader('Gov-Client-Screens', UriEncode('width=1920&height=1080&scaling-factor=1&colour-depth=16'));
RESTRequest1.Params.AddHeader('Gov-Client-Window-Size', UriEncode('width=1256&height=803'));
RESTRequest1.Params.AddHeader('Gov-Client-User-Agent', UriEncode('Windows/10 (Dell/XPS15)'));
RESTRequest1.Params.AddHeader('Gov-Client-Multi-Factor', UriEncode('type=AUTH_CODE&timestamp=2017-04-21T13%3A23%3A42Z&unique-reference=c672b8d1ef56ed28,type=TOTP&timestamp=2017-05-19T13%3A10%3A00Z&unique-reference=ac73430ffdfd9'));
RESTRequest1.Params.AddHeader('Gov-Vendor-Version', UriEncode('My%20Desktop%20Software=1.2.3.build4286'));
RESTRequest1.Params.AddHeader('gov-vendor-license-ids', UriEncode('my%20licensed%20software=8D7963490527D33716835EE7C195516D5E562E03B224E9B359836466EE40CDE1'));
```

I've used all the above HMRC data examples in Postman (https://www.postman.com/) and all are accepted.

Focusing on 1 not working example:-

```
RESTRequest1.Params.AddHeader('Gov-Client-Timezone', UriEncode('UTC+00:00'));
```

I get this response:-

```
"INVALID_HEADER","message":"The header value is not in the format: 'UTC±<hh>:<mm>'.","headers":["gov-client-timezone"]},{"code":"INVALID_HEADER","message":"The offset value (hh:mm) provided is not correct. The header value should be in the format: 'UTC±<hh>:<mm>'.","headers":["gov-client-timezone"]},
```

Any ideas of what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Note that the ones that work are where UriEncode doesn't actually do anything. Adding extra layers of URI encoding where it should not be be breaks things.

Comment: Hi Brian. Thanks for the reply. I've tried without the "UriEncode" and still have the same response. Any working Delphi examples would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You should definitely remove `UriEncode`, because Delphi REST library applies appropriate encoding to request parameters. Some header values get URL-encoded 3 times in your snippet. Take `'My%20Desktop%20Software=1.2.3.build4286'` as an example. It is already manually URL-encoded, then you pass it into `UrlEncode` and finally underlying HTTP client implementation encodes it before making a request to the server.

Comment: No working example and no complete non-working example to fix.